# how do i send emsil csv attachment with python pandas without exporting to csv file ithut using to_csv

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I got the below script to work to export to csv file by reading it from mysql table. But I need this csv attachment not to save to local. instead attach it in email and send it

any idea?

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote
import smtplib


username = "root"
password = "xxxxxx"
port = 3306
database = "DB"


engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:%s@hostname:3306/DB' % quote('xxxxxx'))

sql_query = pd.read_sql(SELECT * FROM table, engine)

print(sql_query)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv (r'localpath/filename.csv', index = False)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringIO` from io, then pass the instance to `DataFrame.to_csv` method:

```py
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> csv_file = StringIO()
>>> df.to_csv(csv_file)
```

To read the object as file, you need to call `seek` passing `0` to reset the cursor, then read the file:

```py
>>> csv.seek(0)
>>> pd.read_csv(csv_file)
   Unnamed: 0  Heading1 Heading2
0           0         1     0994
1           1         2     113G
2           2         3     113N
3           3         4     0978
```

Comment: I got this error TypeError: descriptor 'write' for '_io.StringIO' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Comment: any idea? I am struggling with this

Comment: @wwe34124 Can you edit your question and add the piece of code that throws that error? Also make sure to add the error stacktrace.

Comment: I got it to work now but only on gmail server. I want to get it to work on local email server but getting error:  smtplib.SMTPServerDisocnnected: please run connect() first

Comment: Okay, that means the answer resolves your query of creating file object from dataframe to attach to email.

Answer (score 0):

I use StringIO:

```
from io import StringIO


def create_csv(df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
    with StringIO() as buffer:
        df.to_csv(buffer, index=False)

        return buffer.getvalue()
```